# Combinatorics with ordering significance

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to write Javascript code to calculate the number of possible ways in which a user can make selections given containers $A, B, C, D, E$, each with $10$ items numbered $1$ through $10$ (each container has the same items). I need help with the formula for making this calculation.

[image]

A user must select from at least $2$ containers ($s=2$), but can select from all of them. The order of selection is important. For example, choices a user makes could be:

1. $B_2, C_5$ ($s=2$)
2. $C_5, B_2$ ($s=2$)
3. $A_9, B_1, C_3$ ($s=3$)
4. $C_3, B_1, A_9$ ($s=3$)

My understanding is that the standard way to calculate the number of variants is $I^C$ (number of items ($I$) raised to number of containers ($C$)), which in this case would be $10^5$. I am pretty sure this is incorrect because it doesn't account for the order of selection.

How can I calculate the number of possible user selections for different values of "s," "I" and "c"?

Update: To make this clearer, assume that once a user picks an item from a container it is closed and cannot be opened. A user can select one item and only one item from each container. They MUST select from 2 containers, but can select from more as they wish. The challenge here may not be obvious and is what I am struggling with – because the ORDER of selection matters, there are more possibilities than most well-known formulas will indicate.

Comment: Pick which the first container is.  Pick the value from the container.  Repeat, at least as many times as is necessary noting that the container (*presumably*) cannot be repeated.  Apply [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), multiplying the number of options at each step.

Comment: I am trying to parse your instructions, but they are a bit vague. What do you mean when you say "pick?" Could you please clarify? My goal is to have a formula into which I can enter the variables.

Comment: Is it possible to select from the same container more than once? For example, is it possible to have choices like $B_2, B_9, C_5$? What is the minimum and maximum number of choices allowed?

Comment: No, the same container cannot be selected from more than once. The user must choose from at least 2 containers, but once that condition is satisfied, they can choose from as many as they want.

Comment: Additional clarification then... So, a container may be selected from more than once you say.  Can specific *elements* from the *same* container be selected more than once?  You say that the user must choose from at least $s$ containers, must *those* containers be distinct?  Rephrased, which are allowable sequences:  $A_1B_1, ~~A_1A_2,~~A_1B_2A_3,~~ A_1B_1A_1$?

Comment: To expand on my initial comment, if you can come up with a description of steps that uniquely selects each outcome where *number* of options at each step does not rely on previously made choices, the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of options available at each step (*rephrasing of the rule of product linked earlier*).  The formula you mention $I^C$ is a result of exactly this: $I\times I\times \cdots \times I = I^C$, you have $C$ steps each of which have $I$ options.

Comment: My initial comment was written with the assumption that containers can't be repeated in which case for exactly $s$ selections you have $C\times I \times (C-1)\times I \times (C-2)\times I\times \cdots (C-s+1)\times I = C\frac{s}{~} \times I^s$.(*Here $C\frac{s}{~}$ represents a falling factorial*)  Adding over all values of $s$ greater than or equal to your desired lower amount gives the total.  For example, with $C=5,I=10,s=2$ you have $20\cdot 10^2 + 60\cdot 10^3 + 120\cdot 10^4 + 120\cdot 10^5$.  Once all of the clarifications are made, the final method to a solution will likely be similar.

Comment: I think you may have misread my comment. I said "No, the same container CANNOT be selected from more than once." After they select from two containers, they can chose from as many of the REMAINING containers (once per container) as they want.

Comment: In that case, my most recent comment answers the problem as I currently understand it.  $\sum\limits_{k=s}^C C\frac{k}{~}\times I^k$

Comment: @JMoravitz I think the formula you have presented with the falling factorial is either the one or on the right track. I am going to test it out with small numbers and prove/disprove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of permutations will be a sum that starts with $s$ factors and goes up to $5$ factors (the number of containers). In other words:

```
1st possibility = 50 * 40                <-- chooses from two containers
2nd possibility = 50 * 40 * 30           <-- chooses from three containers
3rd possibility = 50 * 40 * 30 * 20      <-- chooses from four containers
4th possibility = 50 * 40 * 30 * 20 * 10 <-- chooses from five containers

Total number of possibilities = 13262000
```

In Javascript, the code would look like this:

```
var CONTAINER_COUNT = 5;
var NUMBERS_PER_CONTAINER = 10;

function calculatePermutations(s) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = s; i <= CONTAINER_COUNT; i++) {
        var permutations = 1;
        var containersAvailable = CONTAINER_COUNT;
        var choices = 0;
        while (choices < i) {
            permutations *= containersAvailable * NUMBERS_PER_CONTAINER;
            containersAvailable--;
            choices++;
        }
        result += permutations;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(calculatePermutations(2));
```

This code prints:

```
13262000
```

Comment: I tested this using a spreadsheet and verified that it is accurate. The JS code is a huge bonus. Thank you!